# mapping 1024 numbers to unique characters

Tags: java

I would like to utilize Ron Begleiter's code from here: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronbeg/vmm/code_index.html in order to perform some prediction on some sequential data.

The code is based on character comparison i.e., it reads a context (sequence of characters) and as well as a character and it returns the probability P(char | context) meaning probability that char would occur given the context.

My problem is that my alphabet consists of integers from 0 to 1023.  As such comparison such as P( 1 | 111) does not constitute a unique query.  It is not clear if one is asking for P( 1 | 1 1 1)(thee 1s) or P( 1| 1 11) (one followed by 11) or P(1 | 11 1) (eleven followed by 1).  This comparison is ambiguous so I wan to map each number to unique characters to remove the ambiguity.

In particular I would like to explore how to uniquely assign unique characters to each number from 0 to 1023.  Unicode is the way to go from what I've read, and I do not care to print them, the assignment would be solely for comparison purposes.  In other words, I would like to loop over 0-1023 and assign each number to a unique Unicode character.

I'm thinking this is possible and trivial for many, but not for me.

Advise?

Comment: You can also represent each "number" with 4 digits. 0 would be 0000 and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not possible as it would require changes in the prediction code.  The code takes a sequence of characters along with 1 character, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You say "I do not care to print them", but also say that this is for input purposes, to remove ambiguity between "111" and "1,1,1" and "11,1" etc. So they do have to be readable/printable characters... you have a few choices, then:

1. Use fixed multiple-character input like @BobTheBuilder suggests. The difference between "000100010001" and "0011001" would be quite obvious, although maybe not the easiest to read for *humans*.
2. Use delimiters to separate the input like I did in my first paragraph above. "111" vs "11,1", etc.
3. Some combination of the could shorten things down. 1024 = 32*32 so if you have a 32-character "alphabet" you'd only need two characters for each possible value. `0-9A-Z`, taking out `I`, `O`, `Q`, and `Z` (I only picked those four to reduce possible confusion with `1`, `0`, and `2`) would work quite nicely. You could then write "1MFF" or "1M,FF" to mean the two separate values `53` and`495`.
4. Find yourself 1024 consecutive printable characters from Unicode. The [CJK range](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U4E00.pdf) is where I first thought to look, but then you'd be having your users input this information using random Chinese characters. Maybe this would work, but I doubt it. I'd go with one of the first two options before I resorted to one of the latter; there aren't 1024 different characters that could be easily input with a Western keyboard.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to what I was asking.  I looked at http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html before asking the question and I was thinking that Yi Syllables might do the trick.  Seems the last of your suggestion goes along the way.  Now I have to read up the docs on how to actually implement it.  Thanks